# ConfigurationManager use

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I wrote the following code to get ConfigurationManager data, to update it:

```
private static void UpdateConfigurationFile()
{
#if DEBUG
    string applicationName =
        Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
#else 
   string applicationName =
  Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]+ ".exe";
#endif

    string exePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        Environment.CurrentDirectory, applicationName);

    // Get the configuration file. The file name has 
    // this format appname.exe.config.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
      ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);

    string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
}
```

At the end of the code, server is null.

The XML has the corresponding server code:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <forLiDAR.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
            <value>localhost</value>
        </setting>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It it because it's case sensitive? i.e. "Server" != "server"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have a solution to your problem.

Not easy to explain as it is not really your fault,
VS has a bug that is being dragged with it for years now.

So lets take it step-by-step:

1. Adding settings by using the right-click on project and going to settings tab - bad path to follow.. here is why:

If we follow the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx), all we have to do is:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Server = "Now I'm something different than localhost";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

No need to OpenExeConfigration or anything else , just those two lines! and .NET like a charm should be able to save the new setting into the configuration file.. except that it don't :)
Instead it shouts 'Configuration System failed to initialize'!!

So.. we think "alright, they didn't cover it all in documentation.. lets add what we think is missing.." and so we add:

```
var exePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ConsoleApplication58.vshost.exe.config");
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
var oldSetting = config.AppSettings.Settings["Server"].Value;
```

And we will get ... another exception - null reference this time.
So we ask - "what is going there?!" and from debug we add watch for 'config.AppSettings.Settings' and to our horror we see that .NET actually trying to tell us "There is no spoon.."
(or settings count is 0)

So at this point we can conclude this crap is definitely not working with application that use AppConfig.. but it might work with applications that use WebConfig - I didn't test that.
(oh, just to make it clear:'This crap' means adding settings file by using the right-click on the project menu and going to settings tab)

2. Ok... let's try the other method to do that which is Adding a setting file from Add New Item menu, its default filename is going to be 'settings1.settings' and it is going to reside under the general project folder name and not the properties as before.

So I did that too and tested the following lines:

```
var oldSetting = Settings1.Default.Server;
Settings1.Default.Server = "localhost2";
Settings1.Default.Save();
```

This worked - but I need to tell you that the 'Scope' has to be 'user' and not Application.. if its 'application' the setting will not have a setter.. and where did it save the information? in the AppData folder for that user.. which is logical.

This of course means that in order to check manually while you debug what was saved you need to go the configuration file of your app which resides in the AppData folder and not in your debug/bin folder.

3. But all of this is of course not what you asked for...
   Because you want to save an 'application' scope setting - right?
   Well.. you can't - they are not designed for that.
   You can read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

> The ApplicationSettings class doesn't
>   support saving settings to the
>   app.config file. That's very much by
>   design, apps that run with a properly
>   secured user account (think Vista UAC)
>   do not have write access to the
>   program's installation folder.
>
> You can fight the system with the
>   ConfigurationManager class. But the
>   trivial workaround is to go into the
>   Settings designer and change the
>   setting's scope to User. If that
>   causes hardships (say, the setting is
>   relevant to every user), you should
>   put your Options feature in a separate
>   program so you can ask for the
>   privilege elevation prompt. Or forego
>   using a setting.

So, last I will try to show you how your app should look like:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UpdateConfigurationFile();
        }

        private static void UpdateConfigurationFile()
        {
            var oldSetting = Settings1.Default.Server; //to get the current setting if you want..
            Settings1.Default.Server = "localhost2"; //to change the setting.
            Settings1.Default.Save(); //to save settings.
        }
    }
}
```

And provided you add Settings1.Settings file as I mentioned, this is how appConfig could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ConsoleApplication58.Settings1" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>

    <userSettings>
        <ConsoleApplication58.Settings1>
            <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
                <value>localhost</value>
            </setting>
        </ConsoleApplication58.Settings1>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

---

As requested in the comment here is a link to the bug report:
[Configuration in the App.Config and ApplicationSettings](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1465174)

Comment: Please post a link to the [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) bug you sent to Microsoft about this. Because if you're not part of the solution (of bugs never getting fixed) then you're part of the problem.

Comment: I went down this road myself at some point and realized it was just how it's designed to work.  In a way it makes sense that a user should only change their own setting, not the app defaults... unless you want to "Change for all users of this computer."  Definitely falls under a feature that is nearly impossible to unit test against, though, unless you mock or shim ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Thanks for sending them a bug report. My only comment is that you refer to "the MSDN documentation" but don't provide a link. On the Internet, it doesn't exist if there is no link (and often, even if there _is_).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the MSDN link.

Comment: @JohnSaunders nothing to sorry about - I added it after your 2nd message.

Comment: I still don't see it. Where in the article is it? Could you post the link to the documentation here?

Comment: @JohnSaunders sure, here it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx